# problems in running sudo apt update and upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

this is the output:

```
Ign:2 ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 ://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:2 ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Ign:3 ://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 ://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:1 ://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 ://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 ://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:1 ://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 ://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clean and refresh the apt cache by:

apt-get clean

rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

apt-get update